# After deployment navigating with <Link /> in nextjs always fully reloads page

Tags: next.js

I am experiencing something in production which isn't reproducible locally.

The `Link` from nextjs (version `12.3.x`) works well in development and when running the build in production mode locally, meaning that the navigation happens without a full page reload. But when deployed with terraform, all `Link` components are causing a full page reload. Everything else works as expected.

I have a mixture of `Link` children across the application, sometime it's `a`, but other times it's a `button` or simply a `div` or `span`. In every case, the full page refresh happens. That's why I suspect it must be something related with the configuration rather than the `Link` usage, however I am not sure where to start debugging and I am looking for a hint in the right direction.

Comment: What version of Next.js do you use?

Comment: I am using 12.3.x

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when running the app in production mode locally (`next build && next start`)? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back with an answer to this. In my case, nothing was wrong with the `Link` components itself, nor with the build. The problem was with a path rewrite in our terraform configuration (it was rewriting everything in `/_next/*`).

[It appears that `getServerSideProps` fetches JSON files which will be used to render the page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run) Their paths were being re-written and causing a 403 error, which made the page reload instead of allowing me to navigate seamlessly as I am used to with next.

This problem was very specific to my configuration, but my general recommendation is to check whether you are rewriting any path of the `json` files created by next at navigation, in case you are experiencing the same problem only on staging/production.

Comment: I couldn't get your answer, can share what you did to solve this problem